# What does green debugger pointer mean in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

As compared to a normal yellow position pointer during a debug session, what does the green arrow mean?

[image: green pointer]

Comment: It seems to disappear as well when running more that one time.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's when Javascript is **hoisting** variables.

I learnt it from this Udemy course ( you can preview the video).

https://www.udemy.com/course/understand-javascript/

The Execution Context - Creation and Hoisting