# What does the green debugger pointer indicate in VSCode?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, llvm, lldb, vscode-debugger

I was attempting to debug some Rust code using the [CodeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) extension for VS Code. Then this green pointer showed in addition to the yellow one. What does this pointer indicate, and is it CodeLLDB specific or not?

I've looked at the [VS Code debugging docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) but they currently don't mention it at all. And the yellow pointer only comes up in a GIF towards the end.

[image: a green debugger pointer sits two lines above a yellow debugger pointer]

After I took the above screen shot I tried stepping further and then the green pointer turned yellow as shown here:

[image: two yellow debugger pointers sit two lines apart, on the same lines as the previous picture]

Is this a bug in one or more of VS Code or the CodeLLDB extension?

(I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940362/what-does-green-debugger-pointer-mean-in-vs-code) but I'm not sure whether it is related and it has no answers right now anyway.)

Comment: Is it possible that this is showing two threads stopped in the same function?

Comment: @JimIngham I just tried debugging [this toy program](https://gist.github.com/Ryan1729/72becbd5328629c06575f2f98632deea) that has two threads. I was able to add a break point on each of the two thread specific places where `count` is incremented. If I hit the continue button several times then I see the pointer jump between the two break points, but I never see two pointers, so I don't think so?

Comment: Just a guess, I don't use VSCode...  And apparently a wrong one...

Answer (score 1):

I think it's happening when rust is hoisting variables.